# Electron set-cookies HTTP header

Tags: cookies, electron, blazor, electron.net

I have been creating an ASP app and experimenting with bundling it with [Electron.NET](https://github.com/ElectronNET/Electron.NET).
The app works, the ASP controllers are all returning fine on localhost:8001, but none of the request are setting the cookies.
My app allows the user to login, so on first instance the authentication cookie is set on the server, then in each subsequent request each controller queries the user claims.

How do we set the cookie policy in Electron to allow all cookies?
I suspect this might be todo with [SameSite attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite) is that correct?

I have seen [Electron set cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50062959/electron-set-cookie) and this seems along the right lines, but I am still none the wiser.

**EDIT**

I should mention that my client app is using [Blazor web assembly](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/web-apps/blazor), so I am using [HttpClient class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient) and I am calling `SetBrowserRequestCredentials(BrowserRequestCredentials.Include)` on the HTTPRequestMessage tthat should be handling [Access-Control-Allow-Credentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials).
This is probably really important information that I should of included in the first place.

Comment: How are you setting the cookies? What `set-cookie` header is being sent? What errors are you seeing in the console?

Comment: @rowan_m Thanks - See the edit for additional info - I am getting no error, There is no `set-cookie` header at all, so the user login claims and all data are not persisted. I think I will mention this to the ASP guys