# React-electron app: react set cookie value

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-react

I am building an electron-react app, and when I make requests to some URLs I get cookie values included in the response object.

Then when I use other similar APIs, I have to send that cookie in the headers. So, I have to set the received cookie to the `electron.session`.

However, because of electron js, I cannot set a cookie with `document.cookie = cookie`.

How can I implement setting cookies?

[image]

When I use `session` in react.js, the folowing error appears
[image]

I installed fs and path modules but did not fix anything

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Electron set cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50062959/electron-set-cookie)

Comment: No, I cannot use session in react part